# Only function satisfying f'' = -f is a sinusoidal function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it true that the only (non-null) function satisfying f'' = -f is a sinusoidal function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of $f''(x) = -f(x)$ is

$$f(x) = A \cos x + B\sin x$$

where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary real constants.

(The fact that there are no other solutions is a consequence of standard theorems of ODEs. I don't know an elementary proof for this case.)

Comment: Thanks. So would that be an application of the uniqueness theorem?

Comment: Yes, of the uniqueness theorem